# Looping through an object array is different to writing redundant code?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Edit: using js with three.js library.

We use loops to avoid redundant code. However, in this case the for loop doesn't work the same as the 6 nearly identical lines which should do the same job.

```
function isSeen(buttons) {
      var rez = true;
      if (!frustum.containsPoint(musMesh.position)) rez = false; //OK
/*
          for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
              console.log(i); //i does iterate through 0 to 5
              if (frustum.containsPoint((buttons[i]).position)) rez = true;
      }
*/ //^doesn't work
      if (frustum.containsPoint((buttons[0]).position)) rez = true;
      if (frustum.containsPoint((buttons[1]).position)) rez = true;
      if (frustum.containsPoint((buttons[2]).position)) rez = true;
      if (frustum.containsPoint((buttons[3]).position)) rez = true;
      if (frustum.containsPoint((buttons[4]).position)) rez = true;
      if (frustum.containsPoint((buttons[5]).position)) rez = true;
      return rez;
}
```

The for loop causes an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'material' of undefined

while the 6 following conditional statements (which do the same thing) cause no errors and work fine. What is going on?
 Also, *buttons* is an array of *CubeGeometry* with *MeshStandard* material and *musMesh* is the same.

Comment: What library are you using? Where is 'material' defined in your code? 

Nothing is wrong with the for loop. It looks like its from frustum.containsPoints.

Comment: I'm using three.js. The material is defined above in the code as a standard material from the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to achieving this which will ensure a smooth loop. consider following:

```
...some code...
buttons
    .forEach( (button,i) => {
        rez = frustum.containsPoint(button.position) ? true : false;
    })
```

- if `buttons` is an array, it will have the prototype function `.forEach()`
- `(button,i) => { ... }` is a shorthand for `function(button,i)`
- `boolean_expression ? true : false` is a shorthand for `if(boolean_exp) true; else false;`

Comment: you can further ensure the `buttons` collection exists and has some element in it by `if(buttons && buttons.length > 0)`

Comment: Thank you, this does work and looks more elegant. Will be aware of this expression in the future.